# Secure modification of DSA?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, dsa, number-theory

In [DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Operation), we compute the signature $(r,s)$ on $m$ by sampling $k\in\{1,...,q-1\}$ and then computing

$r := g^k \bmod p$

$s := k^{-1}*(m+x*r) \bmod q$

During verification, we compute $v:=g^{m*s^{-1}}*y^{r*s^{-1}}\bmod p$ and then check $r=v \bmod q$.

**Question:** Would it be fine to leave $k^{-1}$ out from the computation of $s$ (i.e., $s := m+x*r$) and then instead check for $g = v$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question:** Would it be fine to leave $k^{-1}$ out from the computation of $s$ (i.e., $s := m+x*r$) and then instead check for $g = v$?

In other words, the check would then be $g = g^{ms^{-1}}y^{rs^{-1}}$

Now, that would not be secure; suppose we have a valid signature for $m$, that is, we have the values $(m, r, s)$ such that $g = g^{ms^{-1}}y^{rs^{-1}}$

Then, for an arbitrary message $m'$, we can compute $s' = m'm^{-1}s$ and $r' = rs's^{-1}$; We have $g^{m's'^{-1}}y^{r's'^{-1}} = g^{ms^{-1}} y^{rs^{-1}}$, which is $g$ (because the original signature is valid); that is, $(m', r', s')$ is a forgery.

Comment: Worse yet, we can recover the private key $x$ because $x=(s-m)/r\pmod q$ and $s$, $m$ and $r$ are all public values.